# ubuntu 23.10 no sound output S(ipc tx error)

Tags: soundcard

my sound card was detected but still no sound output
this is my sound card

```
lspci |grep -i audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron/Pentium Silver Processor High Definition Audio (rev 03)
```

this is dmesg output message

```
[   23.206090] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: ipc tx error for 0x60010000 (msg/reply size: 108/20): -5
[   23.206105] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: HW params ipc failed for stream 1
[   23.206109] sof-audio-pci-intel-apl 0000:00:0e.0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_pcm_component_hw_params on 0000:00:0e.0: -5
[   23.206145]  HDMI 3: ASoC: error at __soc_pcm_hw_params on HDMI 3: -5
[   23.206170]  HDMI 3: ASoC: error at dpcm_fe_dai_hw_params on HDMI 3: -5
[   23.399513] i2c i2c-9: sendbytes: NAK bailout.
```